# Updating data in MongoDB with Rust

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm trying to update a field in a collection of a MongoDB database using Rust. I was using this code:

```
extern crate mongodb;

use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;

fn main() {
    let client = Client::connect("ipaddress", 27017);

    let coll = client.db("DEV").collection("DEV");
    let film_a = doc!{"DEVID"=>"1"};
    let filter = film_a.clone();
    let update = doc!{"temp"=>"5"};

    coll.update_one(filter, update, None).expect("failed");
}
```

This gives me an error saying update only works with the `$` operator, which after some searching seems to mean I should use `$set`. I've been trying different versions of this but only get mismatched type errors and such.

```
coll.update_one({"DEVID": "1"},{$set:{"temp" => "5"}},None).expect("failed");
```

Where am I going wrong?

The DB looks like this.

```
db.DEVICES.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a7bb747a1a650f1814ef85"), "DEVID" : 1, "temp" : 0, 
"room_temp" : 0 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a7bb827a1a650f1814ef86"), "DEVID" : 2, "temp" : 0, 
"room_temp" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty much there. The following compiles and runs for me when I try your example (hint: You haven't enclosed "$set" in quotes):

```
#[macro_use(bson, doc)]
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;

use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;

fn main() {
    let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017).unwrap();

    let coll = client.db("tmp").collection("tmp");
    let filter = doc!{"DEVID"=>"1"};
    let update = doc!{"$set" => {"temp"=>"5"}};

    coll.update_one(filter, update, None).unwrap();
}
```

Another piece of advice: Using `unwrap` rather than `expect` might give you more precise errors.

As for using the mongodb-library, I've stayed away from that as the authors explicitly say it's [not production ready](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-rust-driver-prototype#mongodb-rust-driver-prototype) and even the `update_one` example in their documentation is broken.

Instead I've used the [wrapper over the battle-tested C-library](https://github.com/thijsc/mongo-rust-driver) with good results.

Comment: ive tried enclosing the set in quotes and a bunch of other stuff and it still wont work, im starting to think its just broken. ive started trying to use the C wrapper but they havent got any examples and im still quite new to this.

Comment: The code I pasted above compiles and runs on Rustc 1.19.

Comment: the code compiles and runs for me also, but doesnt change the field, in the code im using "1" but in the db its just 1. does this matter ?

Comment: it works thanks for your help, that took so much longer than it should have.

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for the answer for a newer version of the driver, here it is based on @PureW's answer in an async version:

```
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient, bson::doc};
use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;

async fn main() {
  let client = Client::connect("localhost", 27017).unwrap();

  let coll = client.db("tmp").collection("tmp");
  let filter = doc!{"DEVID":"1"};
  let update = doc!{"$set": {"temp":"5"}};

  coll.update_one(filter, update, None).await.unwrap();
}
```